# ALTER TABLE WITH VALUES FROM SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, stored-procedures

I have a table1 with fluctuating number of columns. (colname1,colname2,colname3...colnamen)

I want to :

```
ALTER TABLE table2 CHANGE COLUMN `columns` `columns` ENUM('colname1','colname2','colname3' .... '') ...
```

each time the table1 gets changed in the structure

I know how to get the column names in a table with:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=
```

But how can I now get them in a string into the ALTER TABLE ?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "dynamic SQL". However, I think you're doing all this wrong.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you very much for the hint. but how can I transform the rows of a table into a array or a string ?

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR '') FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema=

The result would be a string of all columnames. But i really don't understand what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nbk had given what you want - atleast what you made us to understand.

But...

Think of re-designing your whole job. Do not go by your fluctuating number of columns. There are better ways. **json** is one. **Transactional database** is what is been used in lot of projects. Those are the right methods to store / retrieve than having variable number of columns.

Comment: Fine. If you explain more, we shall help you improve / re-design.